# es6-class. Объявление метода через new

Tags: javascript

Новый синтаксис классов позволяет объявлять методы через 'new'?

Например вместо

```
function Foo(param) {
    return function () {
        ...
    };
}
class Bar {
    ...
}
Bar.prototype.baz = new Foo;
```

что-нибудь вроде

```
class Bar {
    baz = new Foo;
}
```

Comment: В вашем конкретном случае оператор `new` не нужен. Совсем. Достаточно вызвать `Foo` как функцию.

Comment: Да. Но проблему это не решает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions), тело класса может содержать только набор [методов](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions).

Иными словами, спецификация **не позволяет вам определять свойства** экземпляров, через конструкцию `class`.

Я вижу два выхода из ситуации:

1. Использовать прототип в явном виде

   ```
   class Bar {
       // ...
   }
   Bar.prototype.baz = Foo('baz');
   ```
2. Привязывать метод `baz` к каждому экземпляру `Bar` через конструктор:

   ```
   function Foo(param) {
       return function () {
           // ...
       };
   }

   // Будем использовать один экземпляр функции для всех Bar,
   // чтобы сэкономить немного памяти.
   var fooInstance = Foo('baz');

   class Bar {
       constructor() {
           this.baz = fooInstance;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на твой вопрос ДА! Сущности классов можно объявлять через `new`
Судя по твоему коду ты используешь прототипное наследование, в es6 это можно сделать через наследование

`class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {}`

и ты сможешь использовать все методы класса Foo.

Comment: Мне нужно не просто отнаследоваться, а создать несколько новых методов которые собирает Foo. Немного поправил пример.